# How to assign data color codes to legend correctly in r

Tags: r, colors, legend

I have created the following scoreplot, but the problem is that the legends doesn't have the right color. My data has 7 categories, I have assigned the color based on these 7 categories to plot the. however, I am not able to assign the correct associated color codes to the legend. How can I do this?

this is my short script:

```
install.packages("pls")
library("pls")
data_PCA<-data[,c(-1,-2,-4,-8,-9,-10,-11,-12,-13,-14,-15,-16,-17,-20,-21,-22,-25,-26)]
data.scale<-scale(data_PCA)
pca<-prcomp(data.scale)
scoreplot(pca,col=data$Core_Lithofacies_No,pch=16,
              ylab="Second Component (24%)",xlab="First Component (54%)")
abline(0,0)

abline(v=0)
legend(1,7,c("Lithofacies 1", "Lithofacies 2","Lithofacies 3", 
          "Lithofacies 4", "Lithofacies 5","Lithofacies 6","Lithoacies 7"), 
      pch=16,
      col = data$Core_Lithofacies_No)
```

This is my part of my data

```
DEPTH   CAL DPHI    DRHO    DTC GR  NPHI    P10AF   P1AF    P2AF    P3AF    P4AF    P5AF    P6AF    P7AF    P8AF    P9AF    PE  RHOB    RT10    RT20    RT60    RT90    SP  Core_Lithofacies_No Core_Lithofacies_Name
4789    8.843   0.048   0.011   59.592  54.151  0.115   0   1.166   0.604   1.202   1.879   0.508   1.248   0.451   0.005   0   2.59    2.628   6.524   10.098  5.396   5.311   -36.244 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4789.5  8.844   0.018   0.019   56.809  40.889  0.069   0.001   1.466   0.476   0.949   1.546   0.263   1.178   0.524   0.001   0   2.937   2.679   8.289   11.67   6.45    6.33    -36.257 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4790    8.834   0.005   0.025   54.694  28.069  0.061   0.025   1.21    0.233   0.906   1.229   0.151   1.008   0.58    0.014   0.009   3.744   2.701   11.761  14.685  8.242   8.041   -36.582 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4790.5  8.852   0.009   0.019   52.615  21.113  0.064   0.085   0.501   0.15    0.961   0.893   0.307   0.696   0.417   0.08    0.077   4.645   2.695   13.937  18.858  9.176   8.912   -38.101 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4791    8.855   0.024   0.01    51.77   23.401  0.074   0.078   0.056   0.228   1.013   0.548   0.464   0.435   0.26    0.185   0.171   5.047   2.669   18.325  22.075  10.868  10.47   -39.779 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4791.5  8.858   0.037   0.004   52.798  30.77   0.082   0.029   0.001   0.209   0.949   0.516   0.286   0.342   0.511   0.218   0.095   5.033   2.647   25.218  22.913  12.936  12.33   -41.234 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4792    8.872   0.037   0.001   55.267  33.384  0.087   0.003   0.011   0.136   0.911   0.571   0.083   0.567   0.783   0.135   0.011   4.779   2.646   31.106  19.485  14.334  13.539  -41.324 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4792.5  8.853   0.034   0.006   57.811  30.163  0.094   0   0.069   0.197   0.826   0.619   0.162   0.943   0.793   0.082   0.005   4.454   2.651   31.977  16.751  14.703  13.819  -40.371 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4793    8.863   0.05    0.009   59.754  29.967  0.105   0.001   0.164   0.501   0.789   0.621   0.461   1.269   0.773   0.112   0.014   4.451   2.625   24.776  13.948  13.287  12.532  -39.243 2   Skeletal packstone-grainstone
4793.5  8.857   0.089   0.007   60.145  37.838  0.12    0   0.664   0.772   0.49    0.851   0.713   1.404   1.001   0.084   0.006   4.611   2.557   20.085  10.323  12.066  11.428  -40.33  1   Brecciated chert
4794    8.845   0.113   0.001   60.206  46.126  0.141   0.001   1.432   0.709   0.161   0.935   1.101   1.508   1.171   0.069   0.007   4.246   2.517   16.308  8.911   10.627  10.128  -42.135 1   Brecciated chert
4794.5  8.844   0.117   -0.008  60.333  46.082  0.16    0.036   1.464   0.608   0.299   0.596   1.416   2.015   0.978   0.081   0.086   3.412   2.511   11.728  9.248   8.437   8.125   -42.395 1   Brecciated chert
4795    8.833   0.146   0.004   58.667  39.132  0.146   0.192   0.813   0.608   0.838   0.366   1.422   2.585   0.679   0.062   0.228   3.093   2.46    9.956   10.082  7.529   7.291   -42.588 1   Brecciated chert
4795.5  8.818   0.182   0.024   56.208  31.132  0.124   0.297   0.428   0.637   1.112   0.341   1.433   2.715   0.618   0.073   0.305   3.353   2.399   10.257  10.395  7.855   7.613   -43.838 1   Brecciated chert
4796    8.808   0.159   0.023   54.036  24.604  0.098   0.301   0.096   0.54    1.089   0.455   1.692   2.56    0.69    0.21    0.461   3.372   2.439   11.093  11.45   8.564   8.303   -45.1   3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4796.5  8.832   0.096   0.012   52.741  19.7    0.083   0.211   0.093   0.5 0.659   0.423   1.984   2.492   0.789   0.37    0.511   3.285   2.545   11.289  12.357  8.913   8.662   -46.069 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4797    8.84    0.05    0.003   52.552  17.243  0.075   0.089   0.232   0.587   0.323   0.408   1.978   2.307   1.076   0.602   0.321   3.688   2.624   12.393  12.829  9.817   9.554   -47.032 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4797.5  8.855   0.03    -0.006  52.842  16.399  0.075   0.01    0.39    0.619   0.104   0.466   1.875   1.789   1.423   0.776   0.104   4.379   2.66    13.401  12.725  10.618  10.355  -48.013 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4798    8.858   0.026   -0.008  52.994  15.637  0.073   0   0.507   0.456   0.027   0.319   1.783   1.51    1.41    0.772   0.053   4.815   2.665   13.962  13.193  11.097  10.857  -48.567 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4798.5  8.862   0.03    -0.005  53.507  15.846  0.074   0.012   0.519   0.275   0.101   0.289   1.25    1.558   1.271   0.658   0.066   4.965   2.658   13.837  13.948  11.132  10.933  -50.204 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4799    8.859   0.038   -0.006  54.531  17.943  0.075   0.087   0.228   0.236   0.387   0.392   0.544   1.544   1.299   0.387   0.068   5.052   2.645   14.364  13.965  11.594  11.418  -50.72  3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4799.5  8.855   0.049   -0.006  55.355  19.327  0.083   0.126   0.035   0.144   0.567   0.441   0.324   1.395   1.304   0.185   0.035   5.088   2.626   15.241  14.391  12.263  12.107  -49.704 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
4800    8.856   0.059   -0.005  55.549  17.593  0.081   0.059   0.048   0.091   0.43    0.348   0.617   1.452   0.96    0.214   0.076   5.019   2.609   15.242  14.761  12.336  12.213  -48.105 3   Peloidal mudstone-wackestone
```

[image]

Comment: It works..thank you very much. really appreciate your guidance and help.

Comment: you're welcome, in fact probably `col=unique(data$Core_Lithofacies_No)` will work

Comment: Yes, you are right again. it also works.